# Add buttons in grid column. ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to add buttons in one of columns in the grid. I try this code

```
listeners: {
render: {
    fn: function(kad_tab){
        var view = kad_tab.getView();
        for (var i = 0; i < store.getCount(); i++) {
            var cell = Ext.fly(view.getCell(i, 2));
            new Ext.Button({
                handler: function(){
                    alert('Suppression')
                },
                renderTo: cell.child(".btn"),
                text: 'Supprimer'
            });
        }
    },
   // delay: 200
}
```

}

```
{header: "", width: 70, dataIndex: '', renderer: function(){ return '<div class="btn" style="height: 11px; width: 60px"></div>';}}
```

But firebug says that he see error here `Ext.fly(this.getRow(c)) is null`.
if i use `delay: 200`. There is no errors in firebug but dont see a buttons in column.

What im doing wrong?

Comment: Accept race give me more answers on my questions?

Comment: Im really try to accept answers. But usually noone aswer me or i find answer by myself. its sad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a simple way...

```
{
        xtype: 'actioncolumn',
        width: 50,
        items: [{
            icon   : url_servlet+'externals/gxp/src/theme/img/pencil.png', 
            tooltip: 'Button click',
            handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                alert("DAMACIA!!!!!");
            }
        }]
}
```